# A smooth, non-analytic real function which is not flat?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, analyticity

It is possible for the Taylor series around 0 of a smooth real function $f$ to converge pointwise to $f$ only in a neighborhood $(-r,r)$ of 0 such that $0<r<R$, where $R>0$ is the radius of convergence of the Taylor series?

The case $r=0$ is the only example I can find for "pathological" converging Taylor series, corresponding to flat functions.

Comment: Take an analytic function (if you like you can take it to be the constant function $1$) and multiply it by a cutoff function which is identically $1$ in a suitable neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Take $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/(x-1)^2},&x>1\\0,&x\leq1\end{cases}$ The Taylor at $x=0$, which is identically zero, has $R=\infty$, but $r$ cannot be larger than $1$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think the function you mentioned cannot be smooth in general, we could consider a smooth extension to $\mathbb{R}$ of the function $f$ restricted to $(-r,r)$ for some freely chosen $0<r<R$. If such an extension does always exist it should work, right?

Comment: @NDB If the Taylor at $x$ is identically zero then $r=0$, since the series does converge to $f$ only at $x=1$. If I am right this is not an example I am looking for.

Comment: Smooth cutoff functions always exist

Comment: @MicheleCirillo The series converges to $f$ for all $x\leq1$. So, $r=1$.

Comment: @NDB I don't know how but I didn't read well your definition, now I see you put $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 1$ and the example works.